# Is $\forall x\exists y (p(x) \lor q(y)) \implies \exists y\forall x (p(x) \lor q(y))$ correct?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I am stuck with a question, and wanted to ask here.

Let $p$ and $q$ be predicates

I know that $\forall x\exists y p(x ,y) \implies \exists y\forall x p(x ,y)$ isn't always right.

But, what goes on when there is two predicates like the one in the title. I'm having hard times to evaluate this proposition: $\forall x\exists y (p(x) \lor q(y)) \implies \exists y\forall x (p(x) \lor q(y)) $

I would be happy if you help me to understand this.

All answers will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It appears to be correct.  For the first statement to be true: Either $p(y)$ is always true, or $q(x)$ is true for at least on $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that holds. In fact, they are equivalent, i.e. we have:

$\forall x\exists y (p(x) \lor q(y)) \iff \exists y\forall x (p(x) \lor q(y))$

The key difference with the general $\forall x\exists y p(x,y)$, where you cannot swap the quantifiers, is that in $\forall x\exists y (p(x) \lor q(y)) $ you do not have any predicate that refers to both $x$ and $y$ at once. Hence, you apply the Prenex Equivalence Laws:

**Prenex Laws**

Where $\varphi$ is any formula and where $x$ is *not* a free variable in $\psi$:

$ \forall x \ \varphi \lor \psi \Leftrightarrow \forall x (\varphi \lor \psi)$

$  \psi \lor \forall x \ \varphi  \Leftrightarrow \forall x (\psi \lor \varphi)$

$ \exists x \ \varphi \lor \psi \Leftrightarrow \exists x (\varphi \lor \psi)$

$  \psi \lor \exists x \ \varphi  \Leftrightarrow \exists x (\psi \lor \varphi)$

Therefore:

$$\forall x\exists y (p(x) \lor q(y)) \iff $$

$$\forall x (p(x) \lor \exists y \ q(y)) \iff $$

$$\forall x p(x) \lor \exists y \ q(y) \iff $$

$$\exists y  (\forall x p(x) \lor \ q(y)) \iff $$

$$\exists y\forall x (p(x) \lor q(y))$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\forall x\exists y(p(x)\vee p(y))$ true. Therefore, there is no $x$ s.t. for all $y$, $p(x)$ and $q(y)$ are false.

- So, if $p(x)$ is always true, then $p(x)\vee q(y)$ always true.
- Suppose there is an $x$ s.t. $p(x)$ false. By hypothesis, there is $y$ s.t. $q(y)$ true. Therefore, for all $x$, $p(x)\vee q(y)$ true.

The claim follow.

Answer (score 1):

The statement
$$∀x∃y (p(x) \lor q(y)) \implies ∃y∀x (p(x) \lor q(y))$$
is true in classical logic and my proof requires excluded middle principle.

If $\forall x p(x)$ is true then clearly $∃y∀x (p(x) \lor q(y))$ is true as well.

On the other hand, if $\neg\forall x p(x)$, then $\exists x\neg p(x)$.
By assumption, $∀x∃y (p(x) \lor q(y))$ hence there exists $y$ such that $q(y)$ is true.
Consequently, $∃y∀x (p(x) \lor q(y))$ holds also in this case.

Comment: At the moment I edited my answer by specifing that my proof is based on excluded middle.

Comment: I convinced myself that some amount of excluded middle is needed, if the following is correct. Assume that $p(x)$ is a decidable predicate, so $(\forall x)[p(x) \lor \lnot p(x)]$), and assume that $(\forall x)p(x)$ is not provable and $(\exists y) \lnot p(y)$ is not provable. Then $(\forall x)(\exists y)[p(x) \lor \lnot p(y)]$ is constructively provable - just let $y = x$.  But $(\exists y)(\forall x)[p(x) \lor \lnot p(y)]$ will not be constructively provable, because if it was then we would be able to prove $(\forall x)p(x)$ or we would be able to prove $(\exists y)\lnot p(y)$.

Comment: I was hoping you might have a better sense than I do of the general phenomenon that is happening there.

Comment: @CarlMummert Well the first hint might be the fact that even *classically* the implication is not valid if we allow an empty domain. We can then have a domain that is classically inhabited, like $\{1\mid r=0\lor  r\neq 0\}$ which is not constructively inhabited (but is neither constructively empty). For example, if $r$ is a carefully chosen real number. Then simply choose $p(x)\equiv\bot$ and $q(y)\equiv\top$. Then the premise trivially holds constructively, while the conclusion only holds if the domain is constructively inhabited.

Comment: @Derek Elkins: thanks. I am personally particularly interested in settings like $\text{HA}^\omega$ where the domain is very inhabited (and my example still works there).  Overall this seems to me vaguely analogous to the independence of premise scheme, but I don't see any precise link yet.   Is there a way to make a precise connection between this, independence of premise, or some other named  principle in constructive mathematics?

Answer (score 0):

Both $\forall x\exists y (p(x) \lor q(y))$ as well as $\exists y\forall x (p(x) \lor q(y))$ are equivalent to
$$\bigg(\forall x.p(x)\bigg) \lor \bigg(\exists y.q(y)\bigg)$$

although the 2nd is only equivalent when the universe is empty.  If the universe is empty the implication doesn't hold.